# How does one get the Bernoulli numbers via the generating function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, bernoulli-numbers

Here is the definition:

> Bernoulli numbers arise in Taylor series in the expansion $$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

I've tried to naively expand $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ around $x_0=0$ and didn't quite understand what should be done with all the $(e^x-1)^{k+1}$ in the denominators of $f^{(k)}(0)$?

How does one get to $$1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{12} - \frac{x^4}{720} + \ ...$$ directly from the definition (without rearranging the whole thing into the recursive formula)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the exponential generating function of Bernoulli numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand $e^{x}$ around $x=0$ and then reexpand 
\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\ldots}=1-\left(\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}\ldots\right)+\left(\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\ldots\right)^2-\left(\frac{x}{2!}+\ldots\right)^3+\ldots=\\
=1-\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\ldots\right)+\frac{x^2}{4}\left(1+\frac{x}{3}+\ldots\right)^2-\frac{x^3}{8}\left(1+\ldots\right)^3+\ldots=\\
=1-\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^3}{24}\right)+\frac{x^2}{4}\left(1+\frac{2x}{3}\right)-\frac{x^3}{8}+O\left(x^4\right)=\\
=1-\frac{x}{2}+\left(-\frac{1}{6}+\frac14\right)x^2+\left(-\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\right)x^3+O\left(x^4\right)=\\
=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}+O\left(x^4\right).\end{align}

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to get from your RHS to $1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{12} - \frac{x^4}{720} + \ ...$?

Answer (score 4):

I know that the question asks for a method not using recursion, but this is just so much easier and cleaner than computing the series for $\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}$.

Given
$$
\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{1}
$$
we can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{(j+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{B_{k-j}}{(k-j)!\,(j+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j+1}B_{k-j}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
which yields $B_0=1$ and the recurrence
$$
B_k=-\frac1{k+1}\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k+1}{j+1}B_{k-j}\tag{3}
$$
for $k\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use generating function to get Bernoulli numbers 
You can use general product rule and take the limit as t goes to zero

$
\frac{d^n}{dt^{n}} \frac{1}{e^{t}-1} = \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}P_{n}\left(e^{t}\right)}{\left(e^{t}-1\right)^{n+1}}
$

Where $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$

Coefficients of polynomial $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ can be found on 
oeis.org/A173018

General product rule looks like binomial expansion but instead of 
powers we have derivatives

$
\left(\left(fg\right)\left(t\right)\right)^{\left(n\right)} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{ {n \choose k} \frac{d^{n-k}}{dt^{n-k}}f\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{d^{k}}{dt^{k}}g\left(t\right)}
$

Calculating nth derivative of t is easy because this is polynomial of degree 1
so our general product rule formula will have only two terms