# Getting Bernoulli numbers via generating functions

Tags: taylor-expansion, generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers

In the below post, in the first answer(by "Start wearing purple" user)
[How does one get the Bernoulli numbers via the generating function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381119/how-does-one-get-the-bernoulli-numbers-via-the-generating-function?rq=1)

$\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\ldots}\end{align}$ is written as $\begin{align}1-\left(\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}\ldots\right)+\left(\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\ldots\right)^2-\left(\frac{x}{2!}+\ldots\right)^3+\ldots
\end{align}$

But expression of the form $\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+x}\end{align}$ can be expanded into $\begin{align}1-x+x^2+...\end{align}$ only if $\begin{align}|x|<1\end{align}$
but $\begin{align}{\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\ldots}>=1\end{align}$
So how is it possible to write the above expansion?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind generating functions consists in placing the terms of a sequence in a Taylor expansion in order to get them back through differentiation. Indeed,
$$
\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{n\ge0} B_n\frac{x^n}{n!} 
\quad\implies\quad 
B_n = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\right|_{x=0} \,\frac{x}{e^x-1}
$$
In consequence, we only need a function defined on a small neighbourhood around $x=0$, that is why you can assume $|x| \ll 1$ arbitrarily small and $\left|\frac{x}{2!} + \frac{x^2}{3!} + \ldots\right| < 1$ in your expansion.

Comment: But the identity x/(e^x-1) = ∑(B(n)*x^n)/n! has a convergence radius of 2*pi. but the expansion done above works for x<<1 only

Comment: The radii of convergence are not required to match, because you are doing several expansions at the same time : at the beginning, $\sum_{n\ge0} B_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ has a radius of $2\pi$, then you expand $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, which has an infinite radius, and finally you want to use the geometric series with a unit radius of convergence. Those radii are not directly dependent on each other, even if each expansion reduces the radius of convergence (except the exponential series in the present case) because of the successive approximations.

Comment: In any case, generating functions are only used in a small neighborhood around zero in the end, whether they possess a greater domain of convergence or not. Depending on what you want to do next, I would recommend you to use the definition with derivatives, it might be less troublesome.